# Personalizar TabControl C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso personalizar um TabControl, como, mudar as cores das abas quando selecionadas, deixar a TabControl sem borda (tipo flat), etc.

Tentei usando o componente TabControl do Windows Forms e não consegui, procurei como tirar essa borda branca, trocar a cor da aba onde tem o escrito tabPage1 e não tive sucesso.

Como posso fazer isso?

[image: TabControl]

Comment: Você precisa focar no que quer e fazer uma pergunta específica. Jogar o problema genérico aqui só vai fazer com que você tenha respostas genéricas (o que não é nossa intenção aqui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os botões podem ser tornados achatados (*"flat"*) através da propriedade `Appearance` do `TabControl`. A propriedade é uma enumeração e um dos valores faz o que você quer.

Já as demais alterações não estão disponíveis para a classe `TabPanel`. Infelizmente você teria que criar uma nova classe de controle para isso, e a complexidade seria muito alta para se ter uma resposta simples. A alternativa é fazer com WPF ao invés de Windows Forms - você vai ter que escrever muito mais código, mas terá mais controle sobre aparência.

Comment: Bom dia Renan, por acaso você sabe de algum curso, tópico, ou algo do gênero que eu consiga aprender um pouco mais sobre WPF, pois tentei mexer e achei bem complicado, pois tem que ficar mexendo em tags, Obrigado por enquanto.